# sql query : double record for joins ... can;t figure it out

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some tables like this :

**I. parent table** :

```
id_client      id_group   package       start_date   end_date     id_contract   is_parent   
1223           88         1234          2012-01-01   2050-01-01   156447        1           
1223           89         34342         2011-04-01   2050-01-01   156447        1
```

**II. share table** :

```
id        package      id_share
1         1234         SS4433  - parent
2         564679       SS4433  --- this is a child
3         564522       SS4433  -- this is a child 
4         34342        SS2345  - parent
5         665456       SS2345  -- child
6         7789997      SS2345  -- child
```

**III. child table** :

```
package       start_date   end_date      id_contract      

564679        2011-01-01   2012-02-01    156447
564522        2011-01-01   2011-05-07    156447
665456        2011-01-01   2012-02-04    156447
7789997       2011-01-01   2011-07-03    156447
```

The question is how to select with one query the parent and all it's children in the same select (based on id_share in share table), that contains the group of the parent.

The result should look like this:

```
id_client      id_group      package         start_date  end_date    id_contract   child_of
1223           88            1234            2012-01-01  2050-..     156447        0
1223           88            564679          2011-01-01  2012-02-01  156447        1234
1223           89            34342           2011-04-01  2050-...    156447        0
1223           89            665456          2011-01-01  2012-02-04   156447        34342
```

I have tried in every way .. but I can't figure it out how to do it .. without union all

I have tried this :

```
select a.id_client, a.id_group, ??package?? , id_contract , ??child_of??
from parent_table a 
join share_table b on b.package = a.package
join share_table c on c.id_share = b.id_share
join child_table d on d.package = c.package
```

**PS: I need to find parents and childs that corespond to 2012-01-01 - 2012-01-31 interval**

where i have put ?? i don;t know .

Thanks

Comment: What is the query you're currently using?

Comment: Why don't you want to use a union all?

Comment: because the parent table is also generated from other 5 tables ... and it will contain 5 mil records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATED, to restrict parents and children by date:

```
select a.id_client,
       a.id_group,
       coalesce(d.package, a.package) package,
       coalesce(d.start_date, a.start_date) start_date,
       coalesce(d.end_date, a.end_date) end_date,
       coalesce(d.id_contract, a.id_contract)  id_contract,
       case when d.package is not null then a.package else 0 end child_of
from parent_table a 
join share_table b on b.package = a.package
join share_table c on c.id_share = b.id_share
left join child_table d on d.package = c.package and
                           d.start_date <= '2012-01-31' and
                           d.end_date >= '2012-01-01' 
where a.start_date <= '2012-01-31' and
      a.end_date >= '2012-01-01' and
      (d.package is not null or a.package = c.package)
```

Comment: I need the package field to contain the parent package number and next the child package number ... `a.package` will contain only parend package number

Comment: It may need `COALESCE(d.start_date, a.start_date) AS start_date` and `COALESCE(d.id_contract, a.id_contract) AS id_contract` but I think this is it.

Comment: @ypercube: Were you looking at this answer before I updated it?

Comment: but it generates lots of lines that i don't need .. (because of left join )

Comment: @MarkBannister: No, I was writing mine when I noticed that yours was almost identical.

Comment: things are a little bit complicated .. because I aslo have start_date and end_date and I want to find the childs that also fit in that date_interval so the left join makes it useless .. :(

Comment: Put that condition in the `ON`, not in the `WHERE`

Comment: because of the `left join` that condition is useless

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8669/discussion-between-ypercube-and-pufos)

Comment: @pufos: I just tried running it with the data supplied in the question and it only returned the 6 rows as requested in the answer - the left join will only produce empty (ie. extra) rows where the share_table aliased c has values with no matching records on the child_table. In your actual data (as opposed to the sample supplied), can a single id_share have more than one parent?

Comment: I have modified my post , because I did'n think of start_date end_date before .. and in the share_table I have shares from different dates ...

Comment: Thank you ... I managed to figure it out in my exact case based on your answer . Regarding my post here .. this answer is 100% working. My real case were a little bit different involving 13 joins so now it;s ok . Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

How about this.

```
select p.id_client, p.id_group, s.package, c.start_date, c.id_contract
from parent p right outer join share s
on p.package = s.package
right outer join child c
on p.package = c.package;
```

Answer (score 0):

A union seems a nicer way to go but it is possible using isnull and outer joins...

```
select isnull(p.id_client, pofc.id_client) id_client, isnull(p.id_group, pofc.id_group) id_group, isnull(p.package, c.package) package, isnull(p.startDate, c.startDate), isnull(p.endDate, c.endDate) endDate, isnull(p.id_contract, c.id_contract) id_contract, isnull(pofc.package, 0) child_of  
from share s  
left outer join parent p on p.package = s.package  and p.startDate <= @toDate and p.endDate >= @fromDate  
left outer join child c on c.package = s.package and c.startDate <= @toDate and c.endDate >= @fromDate    
left outer join (select ps.id_share, p.package, p.id_client, p.id_group from share ps inner join parent p on p.package = ps.package) pofc on pofc.id_share = s.share and pofc.package <> s.package  
where p.package is not null  
  or c.package is not null
```

Comment: Updated to include the date range requirement